# Cython: low level BLAS and LAPACK functions

Tags: python, cython, lapack, blas

I am trying to implement certain algorithms using the low-level BLAS and LAPACK functions via the built-in wrappers in Cython. I am following the guidelines given in [1] and, more concretely, as starting point, I am trying to generate the required pyd files using the examples provided by the author in his github [2]. However, when running the setup.py file, I am getting many compilation errors as it cannot recognize any of the identifiers, e.g.:

> cylinalg\scipy_blas.pyx:91:22: 'ztrmv_t' is not a type identifier

So it seems that the compiler cannot find the BLAS/LAPACK libraries, yet when checking the configuration of, e.g., scipy, everything looks fine:

```
sp.__config__.show()
blas_opt_info:
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/include']
    library_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/lib/intel64']
    libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_blas95_lp64', 'mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'libiomp5md', 'libifportmd']
mkl_info:
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/include']
    library_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/lib/intel64']
    libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_blas95_lp64', 'mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'libiomp5md', 'libifportmd']
lapack_opt_info:
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/include']
    library_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/lib/intel64']
    libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_blas95_lp64', 'mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'libiomp5md', 'libifportmd', 'mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_blas95_lp64', 'mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'libiomp5md', 'libifportmd']
blas_mkl_info:
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/include']
    library_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/lib/intel64']
    libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_blas95_lp64', 'mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'libiomp5md', 'libifportmd']
lapack_mkl_info:
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/include']
    library_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/lib/intel64']
    libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_blas95_lp64', 'mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'libiomp5md', 'libifportmd', 'mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_blas95_lp64', 'mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'libiomp5md', 'libifportmd']
openblas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
```

Do you have any idea about how can I fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

---

Some system details:

- Python 3.4.3 (Anaconda 2.3.0, 64 bits)
- OS: Windows 7 (64 bits)
- Compiler: Microsoft Visual Studio 10

References:

[1] http://conference.scipy.org/proceedings/scipy2015/pdfs/ian_henriksen.pdf

[2] https://github.com/insertinterestingnamehere/cylinalg

---

**UPDATE:**

Ok, so it seems that a quick fix to this problem is to declare by hand those structures the compiler does not recognize (which indeed correspond with the parameters of the corresponding function).

Comment: Just came across this. You should use the interfaces included in SciPy at `scipy.linalg.cython_blas` and `scipy.linalg.cython_lapack`. The repo you referenced is an older version of the code with quite a few bugs.